# Cannot get FancyBox Inline to display

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have tried using the exact code from the demo. Exactly what was on the page, I eliminated everything it didn't need to work and put solely that code in my page.

But all it does when I click is just treat as an anchor tab and scroll up. No JS is triggered to create the FancyBox styling and display.

I have moved files to the directories that I already had set up, but I have also tried it as is with the demo. With the source and lib folders one level above.

Here's the crazy thing. I have another instance of fancybox running just for images, and it works fine.

I have searched and found nothing that helped me. It boils down to something isn't triggering the JS, and I don't know why.

header -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-responsive.css" />
```

Code

```
              <li>
            <a class="fancybox" href="#test1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
              <img src="img/1.png" alt="" />
            </a>
          </li>

   <div style="display: none">
            <div id="test1">
          <h3>Etiam quis mi eu elit</h3>
          <p>
          adfLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque.
          </p>
        </div>
     </div>
   </section>
```

Footer

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script> <!-- jQuery NiceScroll -->
<script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Stick Menu -->
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script> <!-- All script -->
<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script> <!-- All script --> 
<script>
    $(function(){

       var $container = $('.grid');

       $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
         $container.masonry({
           itemSelector : 'li'
         });
       });

     });
   </script>
  <script src="js/jquery.parallax.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Parallax -->  
  <script src="js/script.js"></script> <!-- All script -->  
  <!-- Add jQuery library -->

  <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

  <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

  <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

  <!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

  <!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
```

I'm tearing out hair here. What am I missing?

Comment: You may be missing the fancybox initialization code `$(".fancybox").fancybox()` ... http://jsfiddle.net/picssel/bh2tjk2f/

Comment: No dice. I tried adding it directly on the page, as well as putting it in my script.js file. Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

It was a line in my script.js file that was blocking it. A stupid page loader command that was breaking it. Derp.